# Recognize when value of HTML input is changed

Tags: c#, blazor

Is there a way to call a method when the value of an input (HTML) is changed? But not when the focus of the input is lost but when I type in characters in the HTML input.

I've used @bind to bind an field to the input.

Then I've tried to use @onkeydown and also @onkeyup to call the method. But the last inserted character has not been added to the bounded field yet.

I've also tried to use @onchange but then I'll get the error "The attribute onchange is used two or more times for this element. - I think that the bond is also subscribed this event.

And my last idea was to use an (full) property for the bond and not an field. In the setter of the property I have called the function. But the problem is, that the setter is called when the HTML input looses the focus.

```
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" data-click-to-select="true">
            <thead class="custom-headline">
                <tr>
                    <th class="align-text-top">
                        @indexText.index_table_title<br />
                        <input type="text" @onkeydown="Test" @bind="titleSearch" />
                    </th>
                    ...
```

Does someone has an idea how do solve this problem?

Thank you in forward!

Best regards
Matthias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" @bind-value:event="oninput" @bind-value="titleSearch" />



@code {

    private string titleSearch{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, at each keyboard tap the input event is invoked, and the value of the titleSearch property is update to reflect this...

Hope this help...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Isaac, you can do like this, tested with 3.1 preview version

```
<input type="text" @bind:event="oninput" @bind="titleSearch" />

<label>@titleSearch</label>
@code { public string titleSearch { get; set; }}
```